# problem at implementing cost function for logistic regression

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a cost function for logistic regression and I keep receiving that the function is incorrect and I do not know why

```
def compute_cost(X, y, w, b, lambda_= 1):
        """
        Computes the cost overall examples
        Args:
          X : (ndarray Shape (m,n)) data, m examples by n features
          y : (array_like Shape (m,)) target value 
          w : (array_like Shape (n,)) Values of parameters of the model      
          b : scalar Values of bias parameter of the model
          lambda_: unused placeholder
        Returns:
          total_cost: (scalar)         cost 
        """
    
        m, n = X.shape
        ### START CODE HERE ###
        loss_sum = 0
        
        for i in range(m): 
            z_wb = 0 
        for j in range(n): 
            z_wb_ij = w[j]*X[i][j] 
            z_wb += z_wb_ij 
            z_wb += b 
            f_wb = sigmoid(z_wb)
            loss = -y[i]*np.log(f_wb)-(1-y[i])*np.log(1-f_wb) 
            loss_sum += loss 
            total_cost = (1/m)*loss_sum
        ### END SOLUTION ###
        
        return total_cost
```

Comment: "*I keep receiving that the function is incorrect*" Please [edit] to post the _exact_ error message/s that you are getting. Also describe what is the function supposed to do or output, and what is it outputting instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_cost(X, y, w, b, lambda_= 1):
"""
Computes the cost over all examples
Args:
  X : (ndarray Shape (m,n)) data, m examples by n features
  y : (array_like Shape (m,)) target value 
  w : (array_like Shape (n,)) Values of parameters of the model      
  b : scalar Values of bias parameter of the model
  lambda_: unused placeholder
Returns:
  total_cost: (scalar)         cost 
"""

m, n = X.shape

### START CODE HERE ###
cost = 0.0
for i in range(m):
    z_i = np.dot(X[i], w) + b                                      #(n,)(n,)=scalar, see np.dot
    f_wb_i = sigmoid(z_i)                                          #scalar
    cost +=  -y[i]*np.log(f_wb_i) - (1-y[i])*np.log(1-f_wb_i)      #scalar
         
cost = cost/m                                                      #scalar

reg_cost = 0
for j in range(n):
    reg_cost += (w[j]**2)                                          #scalar
reg_cost = (lambda_/(2*m)) * reg_cost                              #scalar

total_cost = cost + reg_cost

### END CODE HERE ### 

return total_cost
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your indentation, so you should use the second loop as an inner loop which calculates the z_wb by looping all the features and adding b out of the loop since b is added on the summation, not on every iteration. Then calculate the cost function and loss out of the loop as well like this:

```
def compute_cost(X, y, w, b, lambda_= 1):
        """
        Computes the cost overall examples
        Args:
          X : (ndarray Shape (m,n)) data, m examples by n features
          y : (array_like Shape (m,)) target value 
          w : (array_like Shape (n,)) Values of parameters of the model      
          b : scalar Values of bias parameter of the model
          lambda_: unused placeholder
        Returns:
          total_cost: (scalar)         cost 
        """
    
        m, n = X.shape
        ### START CODE HERE ###
        loss_sum = 0
        
        for i in range(m): 
            z_wb = 0 

            for j in range(n): 
            z_wb_ij = w[j]*X[i][j] 
            z_wb += z_wb_ij 
        z_wb += b 
        f_wb = sigmoid(z_wb)
        loss = -y[i]*np.log(f_wb)-(1-y[i])*np.log(1-f_wb) 
        loss_sum += loss 
        total_cost = (1/m)*loss_sum

        ### END SOLUTION ###
        
        return total_cost
```